# Errors when i try use twilio/conversations in React Native

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-conversations

When I try to use [Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations) in React Native I get errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm told that the Conversations SDK team is aware that things aren't working in React Native, but this has been fixed for version 2 of the SDK. There is a [release candidate available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twilio/conversations/v/2.0.0-rc.0) now that you can test with, though there will be more changes before 2.0 reaches full release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are missing the `"events"` module. Node.js as a platform has `"events"` natively, but within the React Native platform I think you have to install it.

Run `npm install events` or `yarn add events` and try again.